# Passing Full Result set to Data Flow Task SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, oledb, execute, dataflow

The Proc inside Execute Sql Task returns Start and End date, 
I stored those values as full result set on an object variable.
Now I need to pass that result set (start and end date) to a data flow task.
inside data flow I will extract data from oledb source based on that start and end date and save the result to a text file

So my question is how to pass the start and end date to a data flow task ,

The start and end date return in execute sql task, that i need to pass as parameter inside dataflow task (select ... from table where created date between start date and end date)

Comment: Are you getting back multiple rows in your Execute Sql Task?  Can you explain more about how the start and end date are related to the OleDb source query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just getting a single start and end date, you could just map those to separate variables instead of storing the full result set as an object variable (change full result set to single row and map accordingly).

However, if you must work with a full result set you can setup a for each loop and then extract the start and end date into SSIS variables (which can then be used in a data flow):

[image]

[image]

[image]